# How to implement an RBF network in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, rbf

This is how I understand an RBF network.

From a set of points $P:=\{p_i\}_{i \in I}$ and values $F:=\{f_i\}_{i \in I}$, an RBF network is an approximation $\tilde{f}(x)$,

$$\tilde{f}(x) = \sum_{j \in C} w_j \phi(x - c_j)$$

The $\{w_j\}_{j \in C}$ are the network's weights, and $C:=\{c_j\}_{j \in C}$ are the RBF center points (centers). The weights $w_j$ are found by minimizing

$$MSE = \sum_{i \in I} (f_i - \tilde{f}(p_i))^2$$

with respect to $w_j$, and $p_i \in P$, $f_i \in F$. Note tha $c_j \ne p_i$ for any $i,j$ which translates into choosing centers from available points and function values first, then making sure that those centers and their values are not in the training data set.

The implementation in pytorch is on [Google Collab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eP-LQ1bm12rrZrdHziUxDYvZ9v0n_fqr?usp=sharing), I'll paste it here:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# TODO(TM): extend with a linear model
class TPS_RBF(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, centers, bending_energy, epsilon=1e-09):
        super(TPS_RBF, self).__init__()
        self.centers = centers
        # Add a last dimension (1) for broadcasting.
        if (self.centers.shape[-1] != 1):
            self.centers = self.centers.unsqueeze(len(self.centers.shape))
        n_weights = len(centers) + 1
        self.weights = torch.randn(n_weights)
        #self.weights = torch.abs(torch.randn(n_weights))
        #self.weights = self.weights / self.weights.sum()
        # Add a last dimension (1) for broadcasting.
        self.weights = self.weights.unsqueeze(len(self.weights.shape))
        self.weights = torch.nn.Parameter(self.weights)
        self.bending_energy = bending_energy
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        
    def forward(self, points):
        # For every point in points compute the dist vector to all centers c.
        assert points.shape[-1]==1, "Last dimension must be 1 for broadcasting."
        deltas = points[:, np.newaxis] - self.centers
        # Compute the radius vector as an Euclidean norm of individual dist vectors.
        radii = torch.norm(deltas, p=2, dim=2)
        # Compute the RBF vector. 
        phis = radii**2 * torch.log(radii + self.epsilon)
        # Add dimension for broadcasting.
        phis = phis.unsqueeze(len(phis.shape))
        # Compute the weighted sum of the RBF vector as a function value. 
        # Self.weights[0] is the bias of the RBF network.
        values = self.weights[0] + torch.tensordot(phis, self.weights[1:], dims=2)  
        # TODO(TM): Apply the Thin Plate Spline RBF bending penalty.
        #bending_penalty = torch.sum(torch.pow(self.weights[1:], 2)) * self.bending_energy
        return values # + bending_penalty

# Define the true function that we want to approximate
def true_func(x):
    return x**2

# All points and values
points_vis = torch.linspace(0,1,100)
# Append one dimension for broadcasting. 
if (points_vis.shape[-1] != 1):
    points_vis = points_vis.unsqueeze(len(points_vis.shape))

values_vis = true_func(points_vis)


# Training points and values
n_training_points = 20 
train_indices = torch.randperm(len(points_vis))[:n_training_points]
points_train = points_vis[train_indices]
values_train = true_func(points_train)

# RBF center points 
# Select RBF centers that are different from training points.
all_indices = set(torch.arange(len(points_vis)))
center_candidates = all_indices - set(train_indices)
center_candidates = torch.tensor(list(center_candidates))
n_centers = 10
center_selection = torch.randperm(len(center_candidates))[:n_centers]
center_indices = center_candidates[center_selection]
# Test that RBF centers do not coincide with training points.
assert(len(set(train_indices).intersection(set(center_indices))) == 0)
centers = points_vis[center_indices]
center_values = values_vis[center_indices]

bending_energy = torch.tensor([0.01], requires_grad=True)
model = TPS_RBF(centers, bending_energy)

# Define the optimizer and the loss function
print(model.parameters())
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

# Train the model
num_epochs = 10000
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    f_pred = model(points_train)
    loss = criterion(f_pred, values_train)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
  
    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print("Epoch: {}/{}, Loss: {}".format(epoch, num_epochs, loss.item()))

# # Plot the results
rbf_vis = model(points_vis)
plt.plot(points_train, f_pred.detach().numpy(), 'o', label="RBF_NN(x_train)")
plt.plot(points_vis, values_vis, label="f(x)")
plt.plot(points_vis, rbf_vis.detach().numpy(), label="RBF_NN(x)")
plt.plot(points_train, values_train, "x", label="f(x_train)")
plt.legend()
```

This example tries to use RBF approximation to approximate $x^2$, and the trainig fails. So far I've tried modifying the number of centers and learning rate. I would like to stick with an Thin-Plate-Spline (TPS) Radial Basis Function (RBF), because of the context I would use this in.

Why does the network not converge?

Comment: Maybe you can compare your implementation with other RBF Pytorch implementations (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/JeremyLinux/PyTorch-Radial-Basis-Function-Layer/blob/master/Torch%20RBF/torch_rbf.py))